# Add axis labels to tableGrob in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using the default table output, the default is to plot the "axis" labels using the parameter names (k1 and k2 in this case). This is useful particularly for comparing cluster membership and the most important thing to denote is which cluster is rows and which is columns.

```
table(
  k1=matrix(1:4, 2),
  k2=matrix(1:4, 2)
)

   k2
k1  1 2 3 4
  1 1 0 0 0
  2 0 1 0 0
  3 0 0 1 0
  4 0 0 0 1
```

I am trying to make use of `tableGrob` to output some tables, composed with other ggplot components in `grid.arrange`. However, the axis labels are lost.

```
grid.arrange(tableGrob(
  table(
    k1=matrix(1:4, 2),
    k2=matrix(1:4, 2)
  )
))
```

[image: missingAxis]

All I want to do is have those included or even include them manually after making the grob.

Thanks

Edit: Attempt with `annotation_custom`:

[image: annotation_custom]

Code:

```
ggTableAxis2 <- function(t) {
  my_grob <- tableGrob(t)

  my_plot <- ggplot(mapping = aes(k2, k1)) + 
    annotation_custom(my_grob) +
    scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
    theme(axis.title =  element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0),
          axis.title.x.top =  element_text(hjust = 0))
  return(my_plot)
}

grid.arrange(
  ggTableAxis2(
    table(
      k1=matrix(1:4, 2),
      k2=matrix(1:4, 2)
    )
  ),
  ggTableAxis2(
    table(
      k1=matrix(1:4, 2),
      k2=matrix(1:4, 2)
    )
  ),
  nrow=1
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure where exactly you want the labels, but it's probably easiest to add grobs to the gtable,

```
tbl <- table(
  longlabel1=matrix(1:4, 2),
  longlabel2=matrix(1:4, 2)
)

nms <- names(dimnames(tbl))


library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)
grid.newpage()

tg <- textGrob(nms[1], x=0, hjust=0)
lg <- textGrob(nms[2], x=1, hjust=1)
g <- tableGrob(tbl)
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, unit(1,"line"), 0)
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, grobWidth(lg), 0)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, tg, t = 1, l=3, r=ncol(g))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, lg, l = 1, t=2)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but the text gets truncated if it is more than 3 characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an empty `ggplot` with mapped aesthetics:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

my_grob <- tableGrob(table(k1 = matrix(1:4, 2), k2 = matrix(1:4, 2)))

my_plot <- ggplot(mapping = aes(k2, k1)) + 
  annotation_custom(my_grob) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
  theme(axis.title.y =  element_text(angle = 0),
        axis.title.x.top =  element_text(hjust = 0))

grid.arrange(my_plot, my_plot, my_plot, my_plot)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but for some reason I get completely a little different results which I have added in the question. The rotation is different and the margins are gigantic!

Comment: That's great, thanks. Stupid question, but how do I actually make the plot smaller? In my RMarkdown file I can change the `fig.height`, but that just shrinks the size of the tables to take up the same relative amount of space. If I run the code in the console (i.e. avoid RMarkdown) I still get the large margins. Apologies, I am new to R!

Comment: Tables have text, and text is defined in absolute sizes. See `vignette('tableGrob')` on how to change the size of the text.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't referring to the font sizes of the text, but of the huge grey area which surrounds my table which is between the table itself and the k1/k2 labels. I would like the k1/k2 to appear right beside the table like in your image. Much appreciate the help.

Comment: you could use e.g. `egg::set_panel_size()` to fix the panel to the table size, but that's becoming really twisted (+ inefficient, inelegant, convoluted, ...); using ggplot2 for the sole purpose of wrapping a grob is a recent trend that I've seen, it's perplexing.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'd have liked to accept two solutions, but I ended up using baptiste's as it seemed a bit overkill to wrap ggplot around the table. Really surprised this isn't a standard feature of the grid.tables though.

Comment: @dpwrussell I've hardly ever used `grid.table` myself, and I don't remember this feature being requested before. It wouldn't be hard to add the option of side annotations, like `top,bottom,left,right` in `grid.arrange` but aware of the table size.